# Flutter Navigation DevTools for Debugging?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a quick solution to Navigate through all the Stateful/Stateless widgets in your Flutter project through some sort of menu listing all of them?

It can get quite tedious to make or find a button in your code and write/remove/comment navigation code to quickly debug scenarios.

Is there such a quick navigation feature? I'm using VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be using Flutter Outline for this kind of stuff it is already available for projects in Android Studio. For VS Code there's a similar plugin which I am linking [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gerrnperl.outline-map). It is called Outline Map.

[image]
You can basically see all your widgets in a heirarchial tree formation and even navigate and extract by clicking on them.